# Is g++ misbehaving with function template overloading?

Tags: c++, templates, g++, clang

I took the following example from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Function_template_overloading
and clang (3.4) seems to be handling it just fine, while g++ (4.8.3) gives an 'ambiguous overload' error:

```
struct A {};
template<class T> struct B {
  template<class R> void operator*(R&){ cout << "1" << endl; }             // #1
};
template<class T, class R> void operator*(T&, R&) { cout << "2" << endl;}  // #2
int main() {
  A a;
  B<A> b;
  b * a; //prints 1
}
```

clang correctly prints 1 (as expected according to cppreference), while g++ gives this error:

```
test_templates.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test_templates.cpp:13:5: error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator*’ (operand types are ‘B<A>’ and ‘A’)
   b * a; //prints 1
     ^
test_templates.cpp:13:5: note: candidates are:
test_templates.cpp:7:26: note: void B<T>::operator*(R&) [with R = A; T = A]
   template<class R> void operator*(R&){ cout << "1" << endl; }            // #1
                          ^
test_templates.cpp:9:33: note: void operator*(T&, R&) [with T = B<A>; R = A]
 template<class T, class R> void operator*(T&, R&) { cout << "2" << endl;}  // #2
```

Is g++ actually misbehaving here?

Comment: VS2012 (MSVC 11.0) also reports this as ambiguous

Comment: Well clang-3.4.2 at my box also reported this as ambiguous. 3.5 compiled it. Although I am not sure if there is much to answer. The link is pretty clear. The operator is ambiguous, but it should be resolved with partial ordering. One can only find appropriate citation in standard. My bet is that cppreference is right.

Comment: @luk32 clang-3.4.2 compiles ok when `-std=c++11`/`-std=c++1y`

Comment: @HongxuChen Yea I know, I wrote it in 3 places already too. But it doesn't seem regarded as c++11 specific feature, because clang 3.5 compiles it even with `-std=c++98`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This example is taken from the [standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf) (this is the draft for c++11).

**14.5.6.2 Partial ordering of function templates** paragraph 3 example:

```
struct A { };
template<class T> struct B {
  template<class R> int operator*(R&); // #1
};
template<class T, class R> int operator*(T&, R&); // #2
// The declaration of B::operator* is transformed into the equivalent of
// template<class R> int operator*(B<A>&, R&); // #1a
int main() {
  A a;
  B<A> b;
  b * a; // calls #1a
}
```

So, the standard itself pretty much say this is legal code. I could copy-paste rules, but one might as well click link and jump to the relevant place. My point is only to prove this is a proper compilable code as defined by the standard.

For what it's worth on my debian `clang 3.5.0` compiled it right away, `clang 3.4.2` had to be executed with `-std=c++11`, `g++ 4.9.1` reported ambiguity in all cases (I even tried 1y).

I am puzzled by `clang` behaviour, though. I thought it might have been ambiguous in earlier versions of c++, the rule to disambiguate was added as a part of c++11 and `g++` didn't keep up. But `clang 3.5` compiles it even with `-std=c++98`.

Comment: you beat me by few seconds, I located that in standard, +1 btw

Comment: @P0W =) Well, I was interested if rules are the same as on cppreference and noticed it's exactly the same example. Not my proudest answer tbh, just copy-pasterino, but it proves the point g++ is wrong.

Comment: Is this a reported g++ bug?

Comment: I'm trying to report it right now, we'll see how that goes (never reported a bug for gcc before).

Comment: @dcmm88 I would report it to clang. MSVC++ doesn't compile it either.

Comment: @black I don't understand why you still think it is clang which is misbehaving? The example is from the standard itself. It's almost like saying that by definition this has to compile.

Comment: @dcmm88 I'm not. *I* would report it to clang. *I* find more likely that one compiler is wrong (which is, partially) rather than two; happy to be wrong.

Comment: I agree with @dcmm88. Since this is an example from the standard itself it has to compile. Any compilers producing errors are misbehaving.

Comment: I remind you only clang 3.5 compiles it. Its previous versions are wrong too?

Comment: Yes, and again 3.4 compiles it with `-std=c++11`. The disambiugation mechanism for this case is added functionality. Some compiler must be 1st to implement new stuff. Just because it is 1st does not mean it's wrong. If you were right, it would mean, example in standard is wrong, and that `clang` devs made a regression an option in 3.4 and made it default in 3.5, and the draft had changed in this regard. Pretty unlikely to me but possible. I guess we will see in some future.

Comment: +1 for research - it's still valuable info luk32! @dcmm88 I'm only sad that M$ don't fix anything for their previous compilers :(

Answer (score 0):

**That call is ambiguos**. GCC is right.

> §13.5.2/1
>   Thus, for any binary operator @, x@y can be interpas either
>   x.operator@(y) or operator@(x,y). If both forms of the operator
>   function have been declthe rules in 13.3.1.2 determine which, if any,
>   interpretation is used.

And in this case, we do have both the member and nonmember function. The built-in version is not included because the left hand operator has class type.

If you called the operator explicitly, there would be no ambiguity. However, when the call is done through an operator (thus implicitly) **there is nothing which can distinguish between member and nonmember**, therefore they're both viable functions which, in this case, leads to an ambiguous function call.

Previous versions of clang report it as ambiguous as well: http://goo.gl/OWsJUv

Comment: I think the rules are different for the template case and the non-template case. As @luk32 pointed out the example I pasted in my question is actually taken from the standard itself.

Comment: It's not true that there is nothing which can distinguish them. The member function is a more specialized template as explained in §14.5.6.2

Comment: @dcmm88 I'm unsure. Your observation is technically right but why does  only `clang 3.5.x` compile it then? I'm trying to go through the standard to find out.

Comment: As you say, previous versions report it as ambiguous. You think they made a regression? It would be hella weird to add functionality (disabmiguation mechanism) to make it invalid. Also the example I found and rules would have to change from the draft to the final version. Also clang 3.4.2 compiles it with `-std=c++11` as I said.

Comment: @luk32 No, simply their `std=c++11` has arguably a bug.